# alternatives of Texture2D.GetData and Effect.Parameters.SetValue(Texture2D) in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, 3d

i have a simple xna game that i want to port that to silverlight, at this time i have two problem:

1- i have a custom effect that needs a Texture2D parameter, but SilverlightEffectParameter.SetValue method doesn't accept an argument of type Texture2D, so how can i set my effect parameter in silverlight?

2- i need to get the pixel colors of my Texture2D(that i loaded from content with ContentManager.Load) but in silverlight there isn't Texture2D.GetData method, how can i do this in silverlight?

i uses silverlight 3d application template(from silverlight 5 toolkit)
(i also asked my question [here](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/240778.aspx/1?alternatives%20of%20Texture2D%20GetData%20and%20Effect%20Parameters%20SetValue%20Texture2D%20in%20silverlight)) 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the GetData, I used the Silverlight Toolkit and wrote a custom content importer for it.  I created a class that holds the color data and can return a Texture2D (with a ToTexture2D method) so you don't have to import from disk twice.  I blogged about the solution here:

http://www.dustinhorne.com/post/2011/12/28/Getting-Color-Data-for-a-Texture2D-in-Silverlight-5-XNA.aspx